# Getting exception org.quartz.SchedulerException: Registration of jobs and triggers failed: Found interface org.quartz.Trigger, but class was expected

Tags: java, quartz-scheduler

I am getting the exception

org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'quartzScheduler' defined in class path resource

can anyone please help me to resolve the issue..

I am using following dependency

```
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.quartz-scheduler</groupId>
                <artifactId>quartz</artifactId>
                <version>2.2.1</version>
            </dependency>

            `enter code here`<dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-context-support</artifactId>
                <version>4.0.0.RELEASE</version>
            </dependency>
```

My code is below

```
    @Configuration
    @ComponentScan(
            basePackages = {"com.test"},
            useDefaultFilters = false,
            includeFilters = {
                @ComponentScan.Filter(type = FilterType.ANNOTATION, value = Service.class),
                @ComponentScan.Filter(type = FilterType.ANNOTATION, value = Component.class)
            })
    public class QuartzConfig {

        // this data source points to the database that contains Quartz tables
        @Autowired
        private DataSource dataSource;

        @Autowired
        private PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager;

        @Autowired
        private ApplicationContext applicationContext;

        @Bean
        public SchedulerFactoryBean quartzScheduler() {

            SchedulerFactoryBean quartzScheduler = new SchedulerFactoryBean();

            quartzScheduler.setQuartzProperties(quartzProperties());
            quartzScheduler.setDataSource(dataSource);
            quartzScheduler.setTransactionManager(transactionManager);
            quartzScheduler.setOverwriteExistingJobs(true);

            // Custom job factory of spring with DI support for @Autowired
            AutowiringSpringBeanJobFactory jobFactory = new AutowiringSpringBeanJobFactory();
            jobFactory.setApplicationContext(applicationContext);
            quartzScheduler.setJobFactory(jobFactory);

            Trigger[] triggers = {
                processMyJobTrigger().getObject()
            };

            quartzScheduler.setTriggers(triggers);

            JobDetail[] jobDetails = {
                processMyJob().getObject()
            };

            quartzScheduler.setJobDetails(jobDetails);

            System.out.println("Here 111212121212");

            return quartzScheduler;
        }

        @Bean
        public JobDetailFactoryBean processMyJob() {
            JobDetailFactoryBean jobDetailFactory = new JobDetailFactoryBean();
            jobDetailFactory.setJobClass(MyJob.class);
            jobDetailFactory.setDurability(true);
            return jobDetailFactory;
        }

        @Bean
        public CronTriggerFactoryBean processMyJobTrigger() {
            CronTriggerFactoryBean cronTriggerFactoryBean = new CronTriggerFactoryBean();
            cronTriggerFactoryBean.setJobDetail(processMyJob().getObject());
            cronTriggerFactoryBean.setCronExpression("0 0/1 * * * ?");
            return cronTriggerFactoryBean;
        }

        @Bean
        public Properties quartzProperties() {
            PropertiesFactoryBean propertiesFactoryBean = new PropertiesFactoryBean();
            propertiesFactoryBean.setLocation(new ClassPathResource("quartz.properties"));
            Properties properties;

            try {
                propertiesFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet();
                properties = propertiesFactoryBean.getObject();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                throw new RuntimeException("Unable to load quartz.properties", e);
            }

            return properties;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It was due to conflict in dependency spring-context-support with spring-support. I removed spring-support and now it is working fine